# Is there a type-safe functional-relational mapping framework for Python which is compatible with mypy?

Tags: python, functional-programming, relational-database

Having come from Scala and functional-relational mapping (FRM) using [Slick](https://scala-slick.org/doc/stable/introduction.html), I was wondering whether there are similar frameworks in Python?

I would like to write database code declaratively using dataclasses and Python comprehensions.  For example, the database model can be expressed using type-annotated dataclasses:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import ClassVar, Set

@dataclass
class Student:
    student_id: int = field(metadata={"primary_key": True})
    name: str

@dataclass
class Course:
    course_id: int = field(metadata={"primary_key": True})
    title: str
    student_id: int = field(metadata={"foreign_key": "students.student_id"})
```

I would like to write database queries as type-annotated Python generators using generator comprehensions:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Generator, Tuple


def get_student_courses(
    students: Iterable[Student], courses: Iterable[Course]
) -> Generator[Tuple[str, str], None, None]:
    return (
        (s.name, c.title)
        for s in students
        for c in courses
        if s.student_id == c.student_id
    )
```

This type-annoted function can be statically checked by [mypy](https://www.mypy-lang.org/), and should be automatically mapped onto the corresponding SQL query:

```sql
SELECT students.name, courses.title 
FROM students, courses 
WHERE students.student_id = courses.student_id;
```

So far I haven't been able to find an existing FRM framework for Python, so I have a setup a new [github project to implement a proof-of-concept](https://github.com/phelps-sg/py-frm). But please let me know if there are existing efforts I should be aware of before I start investing effort in this project.